# Is it mandatory to write a header file for creating a dll file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, header

I'm a beginner in creating dll files. I've been searching everywhere, but found little help, may be because it's a basic thing? I was wondering do I always have to write a header file for creating a dll file? I've already written the .cpp file according to some help from internet. I've built it already & it was fine, but there was no .lib file in the directory so I was wondering is it because I haven't created a header file for the dll? if it is, can you help me writing one for my codes? here are my .cpp code. It's a simple surface area & volume calculation of a sphere code.

```
// myfirstdll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"    //library that defines the pow function
#define M_PI 3.14159 //declare our M_PI constant

/*BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule,
                    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                    LPVOID lpReserved )
 {
    return TRUE;
}*/


//Function declarations
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl GetSphereSAandVol(double radius, double*     sa, double* vol);
double GetSA(double radius);
double GetVol(double radius);



__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl GetSphereSAandVol(double radius, double* sa, double* vol)
//Calculate the surface area and volume of a sphere with given radius
{
    if(radius < 0)
    return false; //return false (0) if radius is negative
        *sa = GetSA(radius);
        *vol = GetVol(radius);
        return true;
}

double GetSA(double radius)
{
    return 4 * M_PI * radius * radius;
}

double GetVol(double radius)
{
    return 4.0/3.0 * M_PI * pow(radius, 3.0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A header file for a DLL is simply used for declaring the exported functions, it has nothing to do with the compiler producing a .lib file.  You can certainly declare the functions directly in your DLL's .cpp file instead, the compiler does not care one way or the other.  So in that regard, the header file is not required.

However, a header file is useful if you plan on using the DLL statically in other C/C++ projects, as the functions would already be declared and thus would not have to be declared manually in the calling projects.

Answer (score 5):

The common practice is to have a header file and a .lib file generated together with the .dll file.

Then, in your project you will use the .h file of your .dll creating project together with the .lib file in order to statically link your .dll to some other application/dll.

So , the best practice is to have a .h and a .lib together with the .dll, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: you dont need the .h to link with the .lib and .dll

Comment: No , you don't. I just stated that this is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need a header file to compile a .dll

Comment: It's usually more work / more difficult to use a dll without a header and import library however.

Comment: It depends on what you want to use it for. I've written a dll in c++ to work with some old FORTRAN code and I didn't need a header.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `prototype of the exported functions` **(return method, parameters, calling convention, etc...)**, this is necessary for the compiler to generate the call to this functions and how to pass the parameters and more.

Normally this is done in a `.h` or `.hpp` file for better practice (the author of the library distribute the header with the library .lib or .dll or both and everyone is happy), but it's not required this way.

As long a you let you known the compiler of the `exported function prototype` (ex: you could write explicitly in the project you want to used, ex: in some .cpp), the compiler would do the right job generating the code.